# Is file being copied

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, file-io, fs

I have a Node.js program that periodically loops through video files in a directory. If a file is added or removed, the program updates a database to reflect this change. When a file is added, FFmpeg is used to generate a thumbnail.

I have problems when I try and run FFmpeg on a file that is currently being copied to the directory. As the file is not complete, FFmpeg cannot generate a thumbnail. If I knew when a file is being copied, I could ignore it, and it would be picked up next time the directory is scanned.

How do I determine if a file is currently being copied, or how should I loop a directory ignoring currently copying files?

Comment: Have you also thought about "If the file is done copying, **is it complete and correct**"?  How are you going to solve that?  Do you have control over the file transfer process?

Comment: @AndrewHenle The copying is done by a user copying or dragging the file into a directory. Hopefully the OS takes care of successfully copying the file. If the file is corrupt in some way the program will exit with an error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two processes, one that writes files and one that operates on written files:

1. write your file to a temporary filename (/tmp/filename)
2. once the copy is complete, immediately link it into your target directory.

Using this strategy, your thumbnail process watches the target directory for changes, which now can be guaranteed to only contain complete files.

See [fs.watch](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) which allows you to "watch" a directory for changes.

Answer (score 0):

Once you find a file, take the current size in bytes, then check the file 1 second later and and check if the file size is still the same. If it is not, it means the file is currently being written to.

Comment: I imagine this would work in the majority of cases, but I often notice that my file transfers take a few seconds to get going, and sometimes freeze for a number of seconds which would cause some false positives.

Comment: Becuase you are using node.js, you can do this with multiple files at the same time. You can increase the check interval to eg. 10 seconds, or increase the amount of checks. I believe this is the only way to do it, don't know of any function in any OS which does what you need it to do.